# Problems using namespaced models and controllers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm developing a Ruby on Rails app and I'm trying to organize my code a bit better. Part of the app is a knowledgebase which is organized into categories and articles - pretty standard stuff.

Here is the way I have everything set up (at least what I think is important):

**routes.rb**

```
namespace :knowledgebase do
  resources :categories
  resources :articles
end
```

**models/knowledgebase/article.rb**

```
class Knowledgebase::Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'knowledgebase_articles'
  belongs_to :category, class_name: 'Knowledgebase::Category', foreign_key: 'knowledgebase_category_id'
end
```

**models/knowledgebase/category.rb**

```
class Knowledgebase::Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'knowledgebase_categories'
  has_many :articles, class_name: 'Knowledgebase::Article'
end
```

**controllers/knowledgebase/articles_controller.rb**

```
class Knowledgebase::CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @category = ::Knowledgebase::Category.new
  end

  def create
    @category = ::Knowledgebase::Category.new(category_params)

    if @category.save
      redirect_to knowledgebase_categories_url, notice: '...'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # ...

  private
    def set_category
      @category = ::Knowledgebase::Category.find(params[:id])
    end

    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:title)
    end
end
```

**views/knowledgebase/categories/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @category do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :title
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**My Problem:** when I try to submit the form (either *new* or *edit*) I get the error:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: category
```

When I setup the form like this: `<%= form_for ([:knowledgebase, @category]) do |form| %>` I get the following error:

```
undefined method `knowledgebase_knowledgebase_categories_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fecd7a78908>:0x007fecd707ad20>
```

The same goes for articles. I'm using Rails 4.2.3.

If anybody could help me or guide me into the right direction I would be really thankful - I have googled for three days now I tried everything I could think of.

**Update 1**

This is the params log generated:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"fjOs...VA==",
"commit"=>"Category erstellen",
"knowledgebase_category"=>{"title"=>"Test Title"}}
```

Comment: Can you post the params log generated?

Comment: Hi @Pavan, I've updated my question with the params log.

Comment: Try changing this `params.require(:category).permit(:title)` to `params.require(:knowledgebase_category).permit(:title)`

Comment: It works! Thank you, @Pavan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you look into the ***params hash***, it has `knowledgebase_category` not `category`. So try changing `category_params` to the below

```
def category_params
  params.require(:knowledgebase_category).permit(:title)
end
```

***An Advice:***

Always look into the ***generated params*** in the ***log***. It really helps a lot in finding the solution to most of the errors.